# Can I use gravitational wave to break electron's double slit interference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, double-slit-experiment, gravitational-waves

Electrons will perturb spacetime. So in principle in a double slit experiment, I can detect the gravitational wave emitted by the electron by a super-super capable detector at very far away, and determine which slit it passes through, without destroying the interference pattern. The measurement is not done by scattering particles onto the electron, but rather waiting for its gravitational signal to reach my detector. What's wrong with this thought experiment here?

Comment: The problem is that gravitational waves are insanely minute even in most bizarre cosmic collisions which we have obtained experimentally, only about the size of a proton. We only have a fair enough *theoretical* picture of gravitational waves emitted by subatomic particles such as [**dineutrons** and spin-2 electrons transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) but not sure how to do detect even smaller gravitational waves due to them than usual.

Comment: In addition to @Proscionexium's excellent comment: There's also the major outstanding question of whether gravity is a quantum force (i.e. can be unified with the known quantum forces). If there was such a thing as a graviton (quantum of gravity), its interaction with a particle would in principle lead to a loss of interference in a double slit setup. That doesn't happen - although the extreme weakness of gravity would likely hide such effect anyway. If there is no graviton, then you shouldn't expect to precisely locate a single quantum particle's position using gravitational detectors.